# Recursive definition of set and axiom of choice

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, axiom-of-choice

I am not sure whether the following construction is recursive or not. Suppose we have an infinite set $X$ and we want to construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}\subset X$  as follows:

1. Choose $x_1\in X$
2. Let $A_{x_1}\subset X$ such that, $x_1\in A_{x_1}$ and $X\setminus A_{x_1}$ is infinite
3. Choose $x_2\in X\setminus A_{x_1}$
4. Let $A_{x_1,x_2}\subset X$ such that, $x_2\in A_{x_1,x_2}$ and $X\setminus A_{x_1,x_2}$ is infinite
5. Choose $x_3\in X\setminus A_{x_1,x_2}$
6. $\ldots$

Can I create a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in this way? My intuition says yes. It looks like a recursive definition, but I we run the algorithm a second time (even with the same initial value $x_1$), we may end up with a totally different sequence as outcome.

Also, I don't see how we can use the Axiom of Choice to construct a choice function on $\{X, X\setminus A_{x_1}, X\setminus A_{x_1,x_2},\ldots \}$ since all these sets, expect for $X$, depend on all the previous choices, and hence are not pre-defined.

**Example:** Let $X=\mathbb R$.

1. Choose $x_1\in \mathbb R$
2. Let $A_{x_1}=\{2^nx_1:n\in \mathbb Z\}$
3. Choose $x_2\in \mathbb R\setminus A_{x_1}$
4. Let $A_{x_1,x_2}=A_{x_1}\cup \{2^nx_2:n\in \mathbb Z\}$
5. Choose $x_3\in \mathbb R\setminus A_{x_1,x_2}$
6. $\ldots$

Can we construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in this way? If yes, what theorem can we use to formally guarantee its existence? For instance, can we do the following?

1. Choose $x_1\in \mathbb R$
2. Assume that we have $x_1,\ldots,x_n$
3. Then, choose $x_{n+1}\in X\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\{2^nx_i:n\in \mathbb Z\}$

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What's the issue you are trying to solve or address?  I don't see why saying "find a set $A_{x_n}$ so that $X\setminus A_{x_n}$" is any easier or more acceptable then just saying "find an $x_n \in X$".  Also you seem to assume $A_{x_1,x_2}\supset A_{x_1}$ so you could get repetiion. Ex: $x_1=1$, $A_{x_1}=\{1,2\}$, $x_2=3$, $A_{x_1,x_2}=\{3,4\}$ $x_2=1$ so $x_{odd}=1;x_{even}=3$.  I'm not at all sure what you *question* is.

Comment: @fleablood The question is whether the example with $X=\mathbb R$ is considered a recursive definition of a sequence. Shouldn't it be true that a recursive function gives hte same output everytime we run it? But in the example we may get different ouputs due to choices. So, what is the formal terminology for a sequence as in the example? Thanks!

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice).

Comment: It's not a definition of *anything* as there is no definition of *which* $x_1$ to choose or of what set to choose.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks! So, what would be the binary-relation here? Also, this kind of construction, can it be applied to create a sequence in a complete metric space? I mean, is the Axiom of Dependent Choice applicable there?